# Angular 6.0.3 HTML Component selector not working

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular6

Html selector of angular component is not rendering. 
Here is the module route file.

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {
          path: 'lms',
          canActivate: [AuthGuard],     
          component: LibraryHomeComponent,
          children: [
               { path: 'book/list', component: BookListComponent }
          ]
     }
];

@NgModule({
     imports : [          
          RouterModule.forChild(routes)
     ],
     providers: [
          AuthGuard
     ],
     exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class BookRouteModule {}
```

After that, I defined the module. This module is a **sub-module** of the system.

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [
          BookRouteModule,
          MatImportModule
     ],
     declarations: [
          BookListComponent,
          LibraryNavbarComponent, /* <== declared here */
          LibraryHomeComponent          
     ]
})
export class BookModule {}
```

In the Library Home Component template file, the navbar component is initialized using html tag.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-content">
  <app-library-navbar></app-library-navbar>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Below is the Library Navbar Component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-library-navbar',
  templateUrl: './library-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./library-navbar.component.css']
})
export class LibraryNavbarComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Comment: did you check console, if there are any errors?

Comment: Yes. The console is not showing any error.

Comment: And the `mat-sidenav-container` is rendering?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just moved ```sidebar``` to another component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to broken Angular Material SideNav structure. Like HTML table, it seems you cannot break the structure of a Angular Material component into different components. When I move `<mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>` to the Home component, it works.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="all-content">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <app-library-navbar></app-library-navbar>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Just restart the app. "ng serve" for cli and it works.